# how to restore mysql default schemas like sakila

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

being new to mysql I start learning how to use mysql workbench and by mistake I removed default schemas like sakila and other using mysql workbench, So How Can I restore them back again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to re-install MySql.

The only reason I can imagine that can cause you to choose other way is if you have lots of custom data into your database. In this case export this data using msqldump utility, then reinstall MySql and then import the data back.

Answer (score 0):

I find the .sql files in C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Samples and Examples 5.6.20\Sample Databases\Sakila So problem solved.